# R : Getting the sum of columns in a data.frame group by a certain column

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a sample data.frame as below, I want to create another data.frame that contains the statistical information of that table by a certain column, how can I do that?

Like for example in the data.frame below, I like to get the sum of each column by Chart.

Sample data.frame:

```
Chart    Sum     Sum_Squares    Count     Average
Chart1   2           4            4         1
Chart1   3           9            3         1.5
Chart2   4           16           5         2
Chart2   5           25           2         2.5
```

Desired output:

```
Chart    Sum_sum      Sum_square_sum      Count_sum      Average_sum
Chart1      5              13                 7              2.5
Chart2      9              41                 7              4.5
```

I have tried below code but the return table only contains Chart and V1. sum_stat is the data.frame

```
  sum_stat = data.table(spc_point[,c("CHART", "SUM", "SUM_SQUARES", "COUNT", "AVERAGE")])[,c(SUM_SUM=sum(SUM), SUM_SQUARE_SUM=sum(SUM_SQUARES), COUNT_SUM=sum(COUNT), AVERAGE_SUM=sum(AVERAGE)),by=list(CHART)]
```

Thanks ahead

Comment: @Henrik, added what I tried.

Comment: see my answer for a correct use of data table. if you have a data.frame, say `DF`, all you need to to is just `DF<-data.table(DF,key="Chart")` and then execute the commands you want by group, plus using `.SD` marker for parts of your data.table to use commands on.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers and suggestions. ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider `dplyr`. Suppose `df` is your data frame, the following will produce the desired result.

```
library(dplyr)
df %.% group_by(Chart) %.% 
    summarise(Sum=sum(Sum), 
              Sum_Squares = sum(Sum_Squares), 
              Count= sum(Count),
              Average= sum(Average))
```

or it can be laid out like that in `data.table` too :

```
dt = as.data.table(df)
dt[, list(Sum=sum(Sum), 
          Sum_Squares = sum(Sum_Squares), 
          Count= sum(Count),
          Average= sum(Average)),
   by=Chart]
```

Comment: That doesn't give the desired result. Think you intended `sum(Average)`.

Comment: I edited `mean(Average)` to `sum(Average)` and added the long hand data.table syntax so you can compare.  Since it's the same function being applied (now clearer since it wasn't `mean(Average)`), `lapply(.SD,sum)` can be used too as in the answer by Sarunas.

Comment: By the way, why do we add up the average? I think it is more meaningful to do a (weighted) average the averages.

Comment: Sure but we have to answer the question as asked, first, so that the answers can be correct. Then add more or comment as you have done to go further.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to advocate using data.table. try this:

```
data<-data.table("Chart"=c("Chart1","Chart1","Chart2","Chart2"), "Sum"=c(2,3,4,5),"Sum_Squares"=c(4,9,16,25),"Count"=c(4,3,5,2),"Average"=c(1,1.5,2,2.5),key="Chart")
```

and then simply:

```
summed.data<-data[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=Chart]
```

find data.table package, read vignette and faq - use it :)

Comment: There's also a new `setDT` function in `>=1.9.0` versions, which allows conversion of data.frames to data.tables *by reference*: `setDT(X)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=Chart]`. `X` will be converted to `data.table` by reference here.

Comment: oh, neat! thank for pointing this out, will definitely keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

In base R:

```
aggregate(df[,2:5],by=list(df$Chart),FUN=sum)
#   Group.1 Sum Sum_Squares Count Average
# 1  Chart1   5          13     7     2.5
# 2  Chart2   9          41     7     4.5
```

As @AnandaMahto points out, the formula syntax for `aggregate(...)` is simpler and cleaner.

```
aggregate(. ~ Chart, df, sum)
#    Chart Sum Sum_Squares Count Average
# 1 Chart1   5          13     7     2.5
# 2 Chart2   9          41     7     4.5
```

Comment: +1, but the formula syntax is a little cleaner, both in terms of input and output: `aggregate(. ~ Chart, df, sum)`

Comment: Absolutely. I'd forgotten that you can use `.` in the LHS of the function.  Hope you don't mind if I add it to my answer.